# azure web application firewall (WAF) customize one rule, for particular app

Tags: azure, azure-security, azure-web-app-firewall

I've set up ASE v2 and enabled WAF. But one of the web apps behind it requires ".axd" requests to be enabled. WAF rules block such requests (.../something.axd) - specifically, I see WAF blocks it with 'rules/REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT.conf'. I'd just remove '.axd' extension for this rule and for one particular web app (url). Can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not supported. But is under consideration.